# Calculating the process time for a synchronous network system

Tags: scheduling

Okay I am trying to understand why asynchronous systems are better that synchronous systems in terms of throughput.

Relating to the calculation done in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17608144). Can someone tell if my reasoning is correct ?

**Lets say I have a system that has 1000 live connections and each connection takes 5 packets to complete and a packet is received every millisecond. Processing time is 0.001 ms(1 micro second). The system can only process 1 packet at a given time, if there are multiple packets then remaining packets must wait until the processing is complete for the present packet.**

My reasoning and calculation-:

So in the 1st millisecond the system receives 1000 packets, all 1st packets of the 5 packets from each of the 1000 connections. Am I right ?

If I am correct then the process time should be calculated in the following fashion-:

**1st packet of 1st connection**

Waiting Time for first packet-: 0ms

Process Time-: 0.001ms

Time taken to completion of this packet-: 0.001 (wait time + process time)

**1st packet of 2nd connection**

Waiting Time : time taken for completion of previous packet = 0.001ms

Process time = constant = 0.001ms

Time taken to completion of this packet = (wait time + process time) = 0.001+0.001 ms = 2*0.001 = 0.002ms

So in the same way processing all 1st packets of the 1000 connections would take = 1000*0.001 = 1ms

So in a total I will be receiving 5*1000 packets = 5000 packets, so processing them will take 5000*0.001 = 5ms

**Am I correct in my above reasoning and calculation ? If not please correct me where I am going wrong.**

Comment: Typical packet size is 1500 bytes. To receive one packet per microsecond you need 12 Gb / sec assuming zero overhead. I'd enquire what is meant by "processing time".

Comment: @gnasher729 Given the information is my arithmetic correct. Because the answer that I have linked to is coming up with a different answer.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.